# How can I use an ElementName binding within a ControlTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, controltemplate

I have multiple TextBlocks which reference different elements in my application.  My code works fine when used directly in the page.  However, I want to create a ControlTemplate and a ContentControl to reduce the duplication of code.

How can I pass a reference to an ElementName into the ControlTemplate from the ContentControl using TemplateBinding?  The following code throws this error:

> "Cannot convert the value in attribute 'ElementName' to object of type
>   'System.String'. Object of type
>   'System.Windows.TemplateBindingExpression' cannot be converted to type
>   'System.String'.  "

In addition to the Tag attribute, I have tried ContentStringFormat which also did not work.

What is the correct method to get this to work using templates?

Thanks in advance for your help,

--- Shawn

Here is the code sample:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
    <Page.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <TextBlock Margin="{Binding ElementName={TemplateBinding Tag}, Path=Margin}" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextAlignment="{Binding ElementName={TemplateBinding Tag}, Path=TextAlignment}" Width="{Binding ElementName={TemplateBinding Tag}, Path=Width}" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="AnotherElement" Margin="10" Text="Main TextBlock" TextAlignment="Center" Width="100" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="AnotherElement2" Margin="20" Text="Second TextBlock" TextAlignment="Left" Width="250" />
        <TextBlock Margin="{Binding ElementName=AnotherElement, Path=Margin}" Text="Here is my TextBlock!" TextAlignment="{Binding ElementName=AnotherElement, Path=TextAlignment}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Width="{Binding ElementName=AnotherElement, Path=Width}" />
        <TextBlock Margin="{Binding ElementName=AnotherElement2, Path=Margin}" Text="Here is my Second TextBlock!" TextAlignment="{Binding ElementName=AnotherElement2, Path=TextAlignment}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Width="{Binding ElementName=AnotherElement2, Path=Width}" />
        <ContentControl Content="Hello!" Tag="AnotherElement" Template="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" />
        <ContentControl Content="Hello Again!" Tag="AnotherElement2" Template="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Comment: Why not create styles and apply them to all the controls that need that style?  Why do you want to define some property on one control and then bind other controls to it?  This sounds strange at best.

Comment: @Brent Storing information in a Tag property used to be a technique with MS Access forms development. It was a cheap and nasty way to pass some hardcoded value to a VBA function bound to some property/handler on your control. We don't need this in WPF as we have a wider range of tools at our disposal =)

Comment: @BrentStewart The end result of this implementation is displaying information in columns using MVVM, Bindings, DataTemplates, etc. I scaled down my example specifically for asking on this site. I chose not to use a Grid and instead use a WrapPanel because I felt it was easier and cleaner to use. I'm binding several properties of one TextBlock to another is because I want my column value to copy the properties I set for its specific header (margin, width, alignment, etc). How would you implement this using styles when for each textblock it would reference a different elementname?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This seems like a funny way to template something, but it can be done, you just have to get a bit fancy with your bindings.

The below will work, but I still dont think this is a good way to template a control

Bind the `TextBlock` `Tag` to the actual Element, then in the `ControlTemplate` bind `Tag` to `Tag` and use the values from there as Tag is the Element, you can use any element from it.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <TextBlock Name="_this" Tag="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Margin="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=Tag.Margin}" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextAlignment="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=Tag.TextAlignment}" Width="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=Tag.Width}" />
    </ControlTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock x:Name="AnotherElement" Margin="10" Text="Main TextBlock" TextAlignment="Center" Width="100" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="AnotherElement2" Margin="20" Text="Second TextBlock" TextAlignment="Left" Width="250" />
    <TextBlock Margin="{Binding ElementName=AnotherElement, Path=Margin}" Text="Here is my TextBlock!" TextAlignment="{Binding ElementName=AnotherElement, Path=TextAlignment}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Width="{Binding ElementName=AnotherElement, Path=Width}" />
    <TextBlock Margin="{Binding ElementName=AnotherElement2, Path=Margin}" Text="Here is my Second TextBlock!" TextAlignment="{Binding ElementName=AnotherElement2, Path=TextAlignment}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Width="{Binding ElementName=AnotherElement2, Path=Width}" />
    <ContentControl Content="Hello!" Tag="{Binding ElementName=AnotherElement}" Template="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" />
    <ContentControl Content="Hello Again!" Tag="{Binding ElementName=AnotherElement2}" Template="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: +1 for stating that this is not a good way to template a control.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This works as I want it to in my application.  Both you and @BrentStewart state this is not a good way to template a control.  In your option, what is a good way and why this is not one?

Comment: yeah there are no alternatives so, its kind of silly to say "its not a good way to do it". Obviously, but what other options are available? Because of the way the visual tree is designed, this kind of restriction comes up so often.