# Unable to bind to a property from within a ControlTemplate using ElementName

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

Consider this pseudo XAML code:

```
<UserControl ... Name="control">
  <!-- ... -->

  <SomeComplexControl>
    <SomeComplexControl.SomePartTemplate>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding
                                          ElementName=control,
                                          Path=SomeCustomDependencyProperty}">
      </ControlTemplate>
    </SomeComplexControl.SomePartTemplate>
  </SomeComplexControl>

  <!-- ... -->
</UserControl>
```

Is there any obvious reason why the binding within the `ControlTemplate` wouldn't work?

Right now I'm using a similar approach and I'm getting a binding error shown in the output window, stating that it "cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=control'".

**Warning:** Using `RelativeSource` is not an option, as the template *could* end up being presented in a popup (meaning that the visual tree won't contain the `UserControl` instance).

Comment: you could use a technique described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283039/how-can-i-use-an-elementname-binding-within-a-controltemplate 
or RelativeSource to find the parent of UserControl type

Comment: @MaximBalaganskiy I came across that post myself and like some other users I'm not really comfortable with the technique. Also `RelativeSource` will only work if the template is presented within the same visual tree as the usercontrol; if it's shown in a popup of some sort, the chain will be broken and therefore the binding won't work. :s

Comment: I'm afraid there is no other way. You cannot bind through ElementName from a template. As for popup controls, Tag is a common know solution to that bingding problem

Comment: Instead of using a Tag (which is a bit dodgy) you could create an attached property or even a custom control with a normal property. That would be totaly legitimate

Comment: @MaximBalaganskiy This is exactly what I hoped I could avoid. :s But you're probably right, this seems to be the cleanest solution.

Comment: How about binding both controls to a view model?

Comment: @MaximBalaganskiy I can't make any assumptions on what would be the DataContext there, unfortunately. :(

Comment: Are you explicitly setting the user control's `DataContext`? i.e `this.DataContext = this;`?

Comment: @MikeEason No I'm not. In fact, I don't want/need to interact with `DataContext` from within the template. Its content should only refer to the control's `SomeCustomDependencyProperty` and work regardless of the current `DataContext` value.